# Combine Multiple rows from mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

right guys im having trouble with one.

what i want to do is have a variable which is made from a mysql query. the problem i have is that it needs to contain multiple rows from the query and combine them into one.

currently i have

```
$lender = mysql_query("Select * from lender where reference = '$reference'");
while($lenderrow=mysql_fetch_array($lender)) {
    $lender1 = $lenderrow["lender"] . " " . $lenderrow["lenderref"] . " " . "£" . $lenderrow["amount"]
    echo '<br />';
}
```

so basically i want it to take this format if it has multiple rows

> blackhorse htfhg125h £250
>
> santander htdhfr58hryf £541
>
> Test 125452asaed2 £760

currently i only get the last result when i echo $lender 1 (obviously because its the last call in the while loop)

Cheers In Advance

Comment: So you want to echo each line? Or do you want to concatenate it into one big string/store it in an array? Both of which are one of the first things one learns with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a other array.

```
<?php
$lender = mysql_query("Select * from lender where reference = '$reference'");
$formated_lender = array();
while ($lenderrow=mysql_fetch_array($lender)) {

  $formated_lender = $lenderrow["lender"] . " " . $lenderrow["lenderref"] . " " . "£" .            
  $lenderrow["amount"];
}

foreach ($formated_lender as $row)
{
  echo $row . '<br />';
}
```

Or, if you would just one variable  containing all the row, replace `$lende1 = ...` by `$lender1 .= ...`

Comment: I think you mean `$lender1 .= ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `echo` inside the loop. A loop isn't restricted to one statement.

```
$lender = mysql_query("Select * from lender where reference = '$reference'");

while($lenderrow = mysql_fetch_array($lender)) {
    $result = $lenderrow["lender"] . " " . $lenderrow["lenderref"] . " " . "£" . $lenderrow["amount"];
    echo $result . "<br />";
}
```

If you want it in an array, you can use an empty `while` loop too:

```
$lender = mysql_query("Select * from lender where reference = '$reference'");
$results = array();

while($results[] = mysql_fetch_array($lender)); // Empty loop
```

Also, you might want to be careful about SQL injection if `$reference` is user-supplied and unescaped.

Comment: this would work but i need to assign the echo to a variable. so i can pass it onto another form.

Comment: @slowie: Then you would use the array.

Comment: cheers buddy i used this instead

$lender = mysql_query("Select * from lender where reference = '$reference'");


$lender1 = null;

while ($lenderrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($lender))
{                    
    $lender1 .= $lenderrow["lender"] . " " . $lenderrow["lenderref"] . " " . "£" . $lenderrow["amount"] . "<br />" ;
}

echo substr($colors, 0);